# ComboBox default value in Qt / C++

Tags: c++, qt

I'm having a combobox that I have called as follow:

```
QComboBox *comboBox_test ;
comboBox_test = new QComboBox(this);
comboBox_test ->setGeometry(QRect(10, 10, 50, 20));
comboBox_test ->insertItems(0, QStringList() << "A" << "B");
```

What I would like to do is to set the "B" as the default value.

I didn't find the way to add that code of line which allows me to do so.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have two alternatives given the example you provided. You can use directly [setCurrentIndex()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#currentIndex-prop) given you know the index, or retrieve the index first using [findText](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcombobox.html#findText)

Thus initially you can use

```
comboBox_test->setCurrentIndex(1);
```

Later if you want to reset to "B" on screen

```
int index = comboBox_test->findText("B"); //use default exact match
if(index >= 0) 
     comboBox_test->setCurrentIndex(index);
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is an easier way call setCurrentText() instead of setCurrentIndex()

```
comboBox_test->findText("B");
```

you can so it in just one line! and it is safe, if "B" do not exists in the list nothing will happen.